# Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name in django urls

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

**urls.py in app1.**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cricprofile'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('<int:player_id>',views.detail, name="detail")
]
```

**views.py in app2.**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Welcome {username}, Your account created Successfully')
            return redirect('cricprofile:index.html')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```

I have created one project with two apps in django.

Actual issue is when I try to access html template from one app to another I couldn't redirect.

When I tried to redirect I'm getting this error **Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change this:

```
return redirect('cricprofile:index.html')
```

By the following:

```
return redirect('cricprofile:home')
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect to 'app_name:view_name' instead of actually returning a template

Comment: Hello! Please use `` when wrapping around short lines of code and explain your logic a bit, thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it seems as though he is dealing with POST data and it is good practice to return HttpResponseRedirect object and using the reverse constructor and the other name of the view method to render the other html template [link]https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect